# why i am not able to download any html page of any website?(i am using android studio)

Tags: java, android, http, url

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{`

For downloading html page , This is not even returning failed

```
        public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls){

                String result = "";
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                try{

                    url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    int data = reader.read();
                    while(data!=-1){

                        char current = (char) data;
                        result+=current;
                    }

                    return result;


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "failed";
            }
        }
```

When I excecute it in **OnCreate** , I get nothing in **Logcat**(Here I print the variable in which I store html page.)

Comment: Hi welcome, please check here to learn more about how to ask a good question  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: on adding more stuff .my question is not getting posted

Answer (score 1):

As seen in your class, you are not passing any parameter(urls) to process.

you need to create a parameterized constructor inside your class to pass data.
like below,

```
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        private String url1;
            public DownloadTask(String url1){
                this.url1=url1;
            }
    //rest of your code
    try{

                        url = new URL(url1);
    }catch(Exception e){}
//rest of your code
    }
```

Hope this helps.